# How to add background color for staticLayout in Android

Tags: android, staticlayout

I want to add background color for below staticLayout background color as transperentblock to appear text clearly can some one help me how can i achieve this

### Code

```
 public static Bitmap drawMultilineTextToBitmap(Context gContext, Bitmap bitmap, String gText) {
        // prepare canvas
        Resources resources = gContext.getResources();
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, gResId);
        android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();
        // set default bitmap config if none
        if (bitmapConfig == null) {
            bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }
        // so we need to convert it to mutable one
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG|Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setAntiAlias(false);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(false);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        paint.setTextSize(8);
        int textWidth = canvas.getWidth() - (int) (16 * scale);
        // init StaticLayout for text
        StaticLayout textLayout = new StaticLayout(gText, paint,
                canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                false);
        // get height of multiline text
        int textHeight = textLayout.getHeight();
        // get position of text's top left corner
        float x = (bitmap.getWidth() - textWidth);
        float y = (bitmap.getHeight() - textHeight);
        // draw text to the Canvas Left
        canvas.save();
        //canvas.translate(x, y);
        canvas.translate((canvas.getWidth() / 2) - (textLayout.getWidth() / 2), y);
        textLayout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: so you want transparent colour right? then why you are using rgb

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int argb (int alpha, 
                int red, 
                int green, 
                int blue)
```

Return a color-int from alpha, red, green, blue components. These component values should be , but there is no range check performed, so if they are out of range, the returned color is undefined.

so use Color.argb(0,0,0,0)

Fully transparent - "#00000000"